# Escape valid XML characters in Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have a String which is looking like this:

```
<tag1><tag2>Text</tag2> > AnotherText</tag1>
```

I am using XMLOutputFactoryImpl to parse that XML into a String, however, I need to get the single "greater than" (right before AnotherText) escaped, too even if it is legal to have it there.

Do you have any ideas how I need to configure my OutputFactory to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the XML api (DOM, StAX or JAXB) then the content will be escaped for you automatically. You can also use a CDATA section for this.

Comment: The last > won't get escaped (I use javax.xml.XMLOutputFactory to work with the String).How can I escape the legal >, too?

Comment: "An <tag1><tag2>&gt;inline</tag2></tag2> > Link" is the Output I'll get, however, I need: "An <tag1><tag2>&gt;inline</tag2></tag2> &gt; Link"

Answer (score 1):

Cannot reproduce your problem. Here is my code (I use default StAX from rt.jar):

```
    XMLOutputFactory of = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
    System.out.println(of.getClass());
    XMLStreamWriter ow = of.createXMLStreamWriter(System.out);
    ow.writeStartElement("tag1");
    ow.writeStartElement("tag2");
    ow.writeCharacters("Text");
    ow.writeEndElement();
    ow.writeCharacters("> AnotherText");
    ow.writeEndElement();
    ow.close();
```

output

```
<tag1><tag2>Text</tag2>&gt; AnotherText</tag1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache common lang library to escape a string.

org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils

```
String escapedXml = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml("the data might contain & or ! or % or ' or # etc");
```

Updated answer:

The best solution is to fix the program generating your text input. The easiest such fix would involve an escape utility like the other answers suggested. If that's not an option, I'd use a regular expression like

```
</?[a-zA-Z]+ */?>
```

to match the expected tags, and then split the string up into tags (which you want to pass through unchanged) and text between tags (against which you want to apply an escape method.)

I wouldn't count on an XML parser to be able to do it for you because what you're dealing with isn't valid XML. It is possible for the existing lack of escaping to produce ambiguities, so you might not be able to do a perfect job either.

Comment: I don't need to get all of the characters escaped, I only need the last one in the example String. This character is legal there but it is also legal to have it escaped there. Because I need to compare the String with another one which escapes all "greater than", it is necessary to escape it here to without escaping the other xml entities

Comment: can you not Escape strings before adding to XML document? please give more detail on whats intended . Or else maybe what you want to actually do is result = myString.replaceAll(">", "");

Comment: I get a String which contains elements like this: <x>{tag1} {/tag1}</x> (simplified tags). I parse them into <x><tag id="1"></tag></x>. It is legal to have HTML entities (like <br />) between the simplified tags so that I am not able to escape ">" before parsing it into XML (The HTML entities need to remain unchanged). What I need to do is escaping all single ">" which don't belong to any tags because they may appear in this String, too (like in the example in the first post)

Comment: http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/ is "HTML syntax checker and pretty printer. Like its non-Java cousin, JTidy can be used as a tool for cleaning up malformed and faulty HTML"

But it can also be used with xml. Check the documentation. It's incredible smart, it will probably work for you. I'm checking for an answer for you